# PHPMailer - Configure your email script - gmail_xoauth.phps file missing

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$mail->oauthUserEmail = "<your gmail address>@gmail.com";

$mail->oauthClientId = "*****";

$mail->oauthClientSecret = "*****";

$mail->oauthRefreshToken = "*****";
```

Hi All, I am a newbie. I am trying to configure PHPMailer to send emails with gmail using XAMPP Localhost.

I was able to get refresh token using the below link as a guide for Using Gmail with XOAUTH2. Now the last step says Configure your email script gmail_xoauth.phps In the examples folder. However, There are no gmail_xoauth.phps file in my entire PHPMailer folder. Need Help please

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

Comment: You've just posted your authentication credentials to the Internet, you'll want to expire your token and/or API key immediately.

Comment: The credentials I have posted are from github guide which are already deleted. I already have all the details safe with me :). But not able to get the gmail_xoauth.phps file to update the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [PHPMailer's github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps) for the `gmail_xoauth.phps` file.

Comment: Yes. I already had a look at it..Do I need to create this file?..If so where should I place this file?

Comment: That is the script that you shall be using for sending your e-mails... Put it along the rest of the application.

Comment: ok..I have configured the code from gmail_xoauth.phps and using it to send the mail but I am getting the below error.

Comment: 2017-12-28 18:48:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s25sm9251567pge.63 - gsmtp

2017-12-28 18:48:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost

2017-12-28 18:48:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [106.201.108.248]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8

2017-12-28 18:48:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2017-12-28 18:48:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

2017-12-28 18:48:22 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

Comment: 2017-12-28 18:48:22 SERVER -> CLIENT: 

2017-12-28 18:48:22 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 

SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: I was able to get through the above error by using 

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

Thanks  Jiri Hrazdil.

Comment: That guide is outdated - look at the gmail xoauth example in the examples folder for one that works with PHPMailer 6.0. Beyond that, you have a TLS problem that’s described in the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Disabling verification is not a reasonable solution - read the guide to see how to fix it properly.